# How to update product meta when the woocommerce order status changes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Please help me with the code, I need the product to be updated when the order goes to the status completed... Here is my outline of the code, I have been suffering with it for 5 days...

```
//Update product meta when the woocommerce order status changes
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'update_product_meta', 20, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'update_product_meta', 20, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'update_product_meta', 20, 2 );

 function update_product_meta ($product, $order) {


 // get product
 $order = get_product( array(
    'post_type'        => 'product', // or ['product','product_variation'],
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'fields'           => 'ids',
    'meta_query'       => array( array(
        'key'     => '_sync_updated',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ) )
) );


    // Get the WC_Product object
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    // Mark product as updated
    $product->update_meta_data( '_sync_updated', true );

    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Which product or products is it about? the ones belonging to the current order or all products?

Comment: About the current product , but it is possible for all products to be updated...

Comment: In my store, the price of the product depends on 2 user fields, and on the number of units in stock, I'm trying to make sure that when buying and changing the order status, the product and the price are updated... When I just update through the admin panel everything works

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a beginner in programming, and I may not understand something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all order products from `$order` obect. use `$items = $order->get_items();`  to get all items of current order.

**for current order product update.**

```
//Update product meta when the woocommerce order status changes
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'update_product_meta', 20, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'update_product_meta', 20, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'update_product_meta', 20, 2 );
function update_product_meta ( $order_id, $order ) {
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Compatibility for woocommerce 3+
        $product_id = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ? $item['product_id'] : $item->get_product_id();
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        $product->update_meta_data( '_sync_updated', 'dsdfdff' );
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

**for all product updates.**

```
//Update product meta when the woocommerce order status changes
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'update_product_meta', 20, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'update_product_meta', 20, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'update_product_meta', 20, 2 );
function update_product_meta ( $order_id, $order ) {
    
    // get product
    $products = get_product( array(
        'post_type'        => 'product', // or ['product','product_variation'],
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'fields'           => 'ids',
        'meta_query'       => array( array(
            'key'     => '_sync_updated',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ) )
    ) );

    foreach ( $products as $product_id ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        $product->update_meta_data( '_sync_updated', 'dsdfdff' );
        $product->save();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sir, I'm sorry, the code doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: When I click the "update" button on the product editing page in the admin panel, the product fields are updated as they should be, I am interested in the _regular_price field,I use a price calculator for 2 custom fields... how can I organize all this?...

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a beginner in programming, and I may not understand something...

Comment: Sir, it worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.

Comment: I created a product post update using cron jobs, I think it's more efficient, even I didn't think of it right away....

Comment: Yes, cron is better when you have more data to update at a time.

Comment: Sir, can I write you a personal email? I need to ask you a question...

Comment: Yes, you can reach me.

Comment: I have sent you my email in the feedback form in your profile...